# Github's new file breadcrumb component

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, breadcrumbs

I am trying to create a similar breadcrumb component from Github. When the user creates a new file for a project, a text input field appears and the user can type in the name of a folder. The moment the user types in the forward slash "/" key, a new input field appears (see step 2 of the picture below). The user can also press the "delete" key and return to the previous step. Anybody know of any components that can create a similar effect.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult using a [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) listener which checks to see which key was pressed, and if it is a forward slash (event.which === 47, per the ASCII table) then handle it by either appending a new input, or prepending the input value and clearing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this library can help you.
https://github.com/fabiodan/breadcrumb